# Vue - Webpack - Force scss @import to be chunked in to a shared file?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I'm currently experiencing a pattern where in Vue I have this in a number of different components. What I'm finding is that webpack is then going ahead and including the contents of src/assets/styles/icons across a number of my component style chunks instead of splitting it out.

I don’t really want to pull it in to main as it isn’t shared by all but I’d like to see if something like webpack magic comments is possible or a way to direct webpack to pull icons out in to it’s own chunk.

I've tried investigating magic comments and cacheGroups to no luck.

It seems to duplicate the contents across each of the 7/8 components it is referenced in.

```
<style lang="scss">
@import 'src/assets/styles/icons

.. more component styles here
</style>
```

I'd like to force webpack to pull the import out in to a common stylesheet it'll chunk in but haven't been able to get it there.

Is it even possible?

Comment: As far I understand ChunkSplitting. If you want a CSS file shard across multiple components you include it globally in the main.js or index.js. Webpack will then, with the help of Mini-extract-plugin, extract the CSS to a common.css file.

Comment: It is part of main.scss which is referenced in main but in some of my child components I import it to use a mixin to render a given icon. It then ends up not getting chunked out in to a common css file and instead it is duplicated in each component